# Mysql optimize slow performing query with many to many table joins

Tags: mysql, query-performance, optimization, many-to-many

I have the following query with joins to a number of many-to-many junction tables:

```
profile_language
profile_industry
profile_contract_type
profile_contract_hour
profile_qualification
```

It takes around 3-4 seconds to execute. When I try the same excluding the many-to-many junction tables the query executes in under 0.4 secs.

```
select distinct `profiles`.*
      , `locations`.`name` as `location_name`
       , `candidate_view`.`last_viewed`
         , CASE WHEN candidate_shortlist.profile_id IS NOT NULL THEN true ELSE false END AS shortlisted
     , CASE WHEN unlocked_profiles.profile_id IS NOT NULL THEN true ELSE false END AS unlocked 
from `profiles` 
inner join `jobseekers` on `jobseekers`.`id` = `profiles`.`jobseeker_id`
inner join `locations` on `locations`.`id` = `profiles`.`location_id` 
inner join `profile_language` on `profile_language`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`id` 
inner join `profile_industry` on `profile_industry`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`id` 
left join `profile_contract_type` on `profile_contract_type`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`id` 
left join `profile_contract_hour` on `profile_contract_hour`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`id` 
left join `profile_qualification` on `profile_qualification`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`id` 
left join (SELECT MAX(created_at) AS last_viewed
                , profile_id
             FROM candidate_views
            WHERE recruiter_id = 43 
             GROUP BY profile_id ) AS candidate_view on `candidate_view`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`id` 
left JOIN (SELECT order_items.purchaseable_id as profile_id
             FROM orders
       INNER JOIN order_items on order_items.order_id = orders.id
       INNER JOIN recruiters on recruiters.id = orders.recruiter_id
            WHERE recruiters.company_id = 37
              AND order_items.purchaseable_type = "App\\Profile" ) AS unlocked_profiles on `unlocked_profiles`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`id` 
left join `candidate_shortlist` on `candidate_shortlist`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`id` and `candidate_shortlist`.`recruiter_id` = 43 
    where `profiles`.`searchable` = 1 
      and `profiles`.`deleted_at` is NULL 
 order by `profiles`.`id` desc limit 25 offset 0
```

This is the explain info:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+----------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                 | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                     | key         | key_len | ref                              | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+----------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | profiles              | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY,profiles_jobseeker_id_unique,profiles_location_id_foreign | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                             | 2826 |     1.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | jobseekers            | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                           | PRIMARY     | 4       | testjobsdb.profiles.jobseeker_id |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | locations             | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                           | PRIMARY     | 4       | testjobsdb.profiles.location_id  |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | profile_contract_type | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY                                                           | PRIMARY     | 4       | testjobsdb.profiles.id           |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | profile_contract_hour | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY                                                           | PRIMARY     | 4       | testjobsdb.profiles.id           |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | profile_qualification | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY                                                           | PRIMARY     | 4       | testjobsdb.profiles.id           |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>            | NULL       | ref    | <auto_key0>                                                       | <auto_key0> | 4       | testjobsdb.profiles.id           |    2 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | profile_language      | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY                                                           | PRIMARY     | 4       | testjobsdb.profiles.id           |    2 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | order_items           | NULL       | ALL    | order_items_order_id_foreign                                      | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                             |    9 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | orders                | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,orders_recruiter_id_foreign                               | PRIMARY     | 4       | testjobsdb.order_items.order_id  |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | recruiters            | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,recruiters_company_id_foreign                             | PRIMARY     | 4       | testjobsdb.orders.recruiter_id   |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | candidate_shortlist   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,candidate_shortlist_profile_id_foreign                    | PRIMARY     | 8       | const,testjobsdb.profiles.id     |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | profile_industry      | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY                                                           | PRIMARY     | 4       | testjobsdb.profiles.id           |    4 |   100.00 | Using index; Distinct                        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | candidate_views       | NULL       | ref    | candidate_views_profile_id_foreign,Index 4                        | Index 4     | 4       | const                            |   21 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index                     |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+----------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Note the junction tables are required to build up a dynamic search query in php and not show in the example above but they would be added to the where clause if a search parameter was entered e.g:

```
and `profile_contract_type`.`contract_type_id` in (1,2,3,4)
```

Also when I change the query to do a count it takes even longer approx 4-5 sec e.g

```
select count(distinct `profiles`.`id`) as aggregate from `profiles`...
```

How can I optimize this query. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact MySQL version ? Unfortunately it's only in very recent 8.0.x version that MySQL is able to use better join algorithms and methods (https://mysqlserverteam.com/hash-join-in-mysql-8/).

Comment: @pifor it's version 5.7

Comment: @pifor  if i remove distinct and replace with group by the query runs in under 0.2 secs?

Comment: You don't seem to use `jobseekers`; get rid of the `JOIN` -- this will speed up the query some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over-normalization.  By that I mean that the schema has data that is normalized when it does not need to be.  This often leads to verbose queries and poor performance.

Instead of having separate tables for type, hour, qualifications, industry, language, etc, have a column for each.

Also have

```
profiles:  INDEX(deleted_at, searchable, id)
```

There may be more suggestions; come back after fixing the normalization.

**More**

Assuming the table is InnoDB and that `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, ...

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM profiles
```

is inefficient for two reasons.  `DISTINCT` is unnecessary because `id` values are distinct anyway.  And all it can do is count the number of rows.  But that is better done via `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM profiles`.  At this point, the Optimizer picks the smallest index and walks through that BTree.

In a complex query that has exactly this `WHERE .. ORDER BY .. LIMIT`:

```
    where `profiles`.`searchable` = 1 
      and `profiles`.`deleted_at` is NULL 
 order by `profiles`.`id` desc limit 25 offset 0
```

then the Optimizer would *consider* using the index I suggested.  However, it would check to see how many rows are likely to be involved.  If more than about 20% of the table needs to be accessed, it will punt on the index and simply do a table scan.

**`LEFT JOIN` vs subquery...**

Older versions of MySQL did a terrible job of optimizing

```
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... ) AS x ON ...
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... ) AS y ON ...
```

It seems, in your case, that these are each returning 1 row (or maybe `NULL`).  Here is an optimization that helps in all versions.  Instead of

```
SELECT  ...,
        candidate_view,
        ...
    FROM ...
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... ) AS candidate_view ON ...
    ...
```

move that derived table into the main `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT  ...,
        ( SELECT  MAX(created_at)
            FROM  candidate_views
            WHERE  recruiter_id = 43
              AND  profile_id = profiles.id  -- correlated subquery
        ) AS last_viewed,
        ...
    FROM ...
    ...
```

with `INDEX(recruiter_id, profile_id, created_at)`

You get the same results, including the `NULL` case, but it often runs faster.  Do it for `unlocked_profiles`, also.

Comment: hi why would you add `id` in the above compound index considering `id` is primary key?

Comment: also if change the query to do an aggregate: `select count(distinct profiles.id) as aggregate from profiles...` why does the above index never get used - when I do explain the index does not get used on the profiles table. I even updated the index to exclude `id` since the count query does not use order by clause in the query but the index still doesn't get used and it's slower than the select?

Comment: thanks for the additional explanation. The reason I'm having to use distinct is because a profile can belong to more than one `language`, `industry`, `contract_type`...etc which are part of the junction tables, which then comes back to your over-normalization suggestion. The database was originally designed textbook style and now it would be huge job to refactor as it would include changing a bunch of business logic. I never had these issues with SQL server considering the table only has 3000 row and its not an overcomplex query, MySQL seems to perform very poorly in comparison.

Comment: @adam78 - I added a section.

Comment: hi, if I move `candidate_view` into the select, how do I return just the last_viewed value, currently the sub query returns two values: profile_id and last_viewed since it's being grouped by profile_id. Do I have to put it inside another subquery?

Comment: @adam78 - I modified my answer; see the diff.  (I hope that addresses your question.)

Comment: Many thanks. It has tremendously reduced execution time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to select required profile ids first and then join other columns:

```
select `profiles`.*
      , `locations`.`name` as `location_name`
       , `candidate_view`.`last_viewed`
         , CASE WHEN candidate_shortlist.profile_id IS NOT NULL THEN true ELSE false END AS shortlisted
     , CASE WHEN unlocked_profiles.profile_id IS NOT NULL THEN true ELSE false END AS unlocked 
from (select distinct `profiles`.id
        from `profiles` 
        inner join `jobseekers` on `jobseekers`.`id` = `profiles`.`jobseeker_id`
        inner join `locations` on `locations`.`id` = `profiles`.`location_id` 
        inner join `profile_language` on `profile_language`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`id` 
        inner join `profile_industry` on `profile_industry`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`id` 
        left join `profile_contract_type` on `profile_contract_type`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`id` 
        left join `profile_contract_hour` on `profile_contract_hour`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`id` 
        left join `profile_qualification` on `profile_qualification`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`id` 
        where `profiles`.`searchable` = 1 
      and `profiles`.`deleted_at` is NULL 
 order by `profiles`.`id` desc limit 25 offset 0
    ) AS p
inner join `profiles` on p.id = `profiles`.id
inner join `locations` on `locations`.`id` = `profiles`.`location_id` 
left join (SELECT MAX(created_at) AS last_viewed
                , profile_id
             FROM candidate_views
            WHERE recruiter_id = 43 
             GROUP BY profile_id ) AS candidate_view on `candidate_view`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`id` 
left JOIN (SELECT order_items.purchaseable_id as profile_id
             FROM orders
       INNER JOIN order_items on order_items.order_id = orders.id
       INNER JOIN recruiters on recruiters.id = orders.recruiter_id
            WHERE recruiters.company_id = 37
              AND order_items.purchaseable_type = "App\\Profile" ) AS unlocked_profiles on `unlocked_profiles`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`id` 
left join `candidate_shortlist` on `candidate_shortlist`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`id` and `candidate_shortlist`.`recruiter_id` = 43 
order by `profiles`.`id` desc
```

Comment: if i keep my query as is and remove distinct and replace with group by the query runs in under 0.2sec

Comment: @adam78 please compare it with my version. Also - what will you do if ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode will be enabled (like it should be)?

Comment: hi your query is also fast but if I exclude the limit clause in the subquery it once again becomes slow?

Comment: @adam78 it is optimized for limit but even without limit it may work faster than your original one because it doesn't need to sort long rows to eliminate their copies (distinct is applied to the whole row)